# scala sbt console to include logback

Tags: scala, logback

I am trying to use logback with slf4j in my scala application. I have included the following in build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.5" 
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.3"
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-core" % "1.1.3"
```

I tried to invoke `sbt console -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml -DLOG_DIR=.`

But I am seeing multiple bindings (log4j and logback) in sbt classpath.

```
  SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:~/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
  SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:~/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
  SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

I am not sure how the log4j jar is pulled to the .ivy2 .

build.sbt

```
 libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.2.1"
 libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.1"
 libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.2.1"
 libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector-java" % "1.2.1"
 libraryDependencies += "com.google.protobuf" % "protobuf-java" % "2.5.0"
 libraryDependencies += "spark.jobserver" % "job-server-api" % "0.5.0" % "provided"
 libraryDependencies += "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "2.5.3"
 libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test"
 libraryDependencies += "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "2.0.0"
 libraryDependencies += "net.sf.opencsv" % "opencsv" % "2.3"
 libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.5"
 libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.3"
 libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-core" % "1.1.3"
```

**Questions:**

1) Is the dependency jars in my build.sbt is downloading log4j ?

2) How do I make sure that the slf4j binds with logback only in sbt console?